# What is the upper bound on the number of antipodal pairs?

Tags: geometry, computational-geometry, convex-hull

Antipodal pair is pair of vertices x,y such that we can draw parallel tangents to convex-hull H through vertex x and y without intersecting H.

I found many algorithms to find such pairs, but i am not able to derive the upper bound on number of possible pairs.

Can somebody give the upper bound for convex-hull of n numbers and prove it?

Comment: See Computational Geometry by Preparata & Shamos, theorem 4.18. As you rotate a tangent line around the polygon, it touches every vertex in turn (N moves); at the same time, the antipodal vertex also advances on the outline (N moves, there is no backtracking). There are exactly N pairs, when no edges are parallel. With parallel edges (at most N/2 pairs), the number of antipodal pairs does not exceed 3N/2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See Computational Geometry by Preparata & Shamos, theorem 4.18.

As you rotate a tangent line around the polygon, it touches every vertex in turn (`N` moves); at the same time, the antipodal vertex also advances on the outline (`N` moves, there is no backtracking).

When the are no parallel edges, there are exactly `N` pairs (no move on one side coincides with a move on the other). When there are parallel edges, an extra pair is possible and the total number is `N + P`, where `P` is the number of parallel edge pairs, at most `N/2`.

Comment: I am not able to find the book. can you please mention the proof of this that will be so helpfull. thanks

Comment: No, the text is too long. But the principle is obvious.

Comment: please upload pic or that text, you don't need to type.

Comment: I claim that it suffices to enumerate the pairs by means of cases 2 and 3 only (cases 1 bring no additional pair). Cases 2 gives two pairs and cases 4 gives four of them. But by removing duplicates you get 1 and 2 pairs respectively. Total `(N-P)+2P = N+P`.